# Understanding simple for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

Why does the following code produces

```
x=10:14
for (i in x) {
    print(x)
}
```

this output

```
[1] 10 11 12 13 14
[1] 10 11 12 13 14
[1] 10 11 12 13 14
[1] 10 11 12 13 14
[1] 10 11 12 13 14
```

I thought the for loop would execute 5 times. That is for `x=10,x=11,x=12,x=13,x=14` and at each time print `x` so that it would just give the output `10 11 12 13 14`.

Why does it loop 25 times?

I am completely new to R. So can someone please tell me what is happening here

Comment: It didn't loop 25 times. Did you mean for it to print `i`?

Comment: This tutorial has examples of the loop you are trying http://www.endmemo.com/program/R/forloop.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have first defined a sequence `x <- 10:14`. Since you are a beginner in R, it is worth pointing out that it is generally considered as bad practice to use `=` for assignments, although R tolerates such 'dialect' that is typically used by inexperienced R programmers with a background in other programming languages.

Anyway, your looping variable in this case is `i`. The loop runs five times, as the value of `i` traverses the range defined by `x`, which is 10, 11, 12, 13, 14.

In your loop, however, you never use the value of `i`. For instance, you could simply use `print(i)`, as suggested in a comment above, and see how the value changes from 10 to 14. Instead, you are printing each time the value of `x`, which is a vector defined outside the loop and that is never changed. This vector `x` contains five elements 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, which are displayed each time the function `print(x)` is called.  Since `x` contains five numbers, you obtain a total of 25 printed numbers in your output.

In conclusion, your loop prints five times the same vector containing five elements. 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is working as expected and as it should have been working in other languages

Lets see an example
in java :

```
List<Integer> y=Arrays.asList(10,11,12,13,14);
for(int i : y)
{
System.out.println(y);
}
```

It would have done the same. Printed the value of complete List y five times each for value of i=10,11,12,13,14. Here is the output

```
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

The same is happening in R. If you want to print the list of elements in x you can do either

```
x<-10:14
for (i in x) {
    print(i)
}
```

It will work because i itself is going through the values of x.

or you can do if you want to relate with other programming languages.

```
x<-10:14
for (i in seq_along(x)) {
    print(x[i])
}
```